# wp8 public string is not wrapping in programatically created Text Block

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Hi Guys I'm working on `Windows Phone 8 application`. Here I got problem in wrapping text Block text.

When my string array was not public then wrapping is working fine, while when I created my string array public then wrapping does not work...!

I am not able to find my error.

My  code is here

```
int a =1;
   ScrollViewer scroll = new ScrollViewer();

   string[] questions = new string[]
   {   "Question :\n What is OOPS?   \n\n Answer: \n  Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm based on the concept of objects which are data structures that contain data in the form of fields often known as attributes and code in the form of procedures often known as methods. There are a few principle concepts that form the foundation of object-oriented programming: 1- Object \n 2- Class \n 3- Abstraction \n 4- Polymorphism \n 5- Inheritance \n 6- Encapsulation \n 7- Overloading & OverRiding   "
   };

   int i;

   private void showContent()
   {
       Grid ContentPanel = new Grid();
       ContentPanel.Height = 400;
       ContentPanel.Width = 440;

       ContentPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);

       scroll.Height = 400;
       scroll.Width = 440;
       scroll.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
       scroll.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;

       TextBlock text_question = new TextBlock();
       text_question.Height = Double.NaN;
       text_question.Width = 420;

       // text_question.Text = "Arsal Are you going.? If user is not login then there at detail page user want to add product in his wish list then there is popup comes .... Please Login  There should be align text. when user goes to detail screen then first show batch 42 % off after that shows 0% off. more share button and like button alignment also changes slowly. user can identify easily.";

       text_question.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
       text_question.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);

       scroll.Content = questions[0];
       ContentPanel.Children.Add(scroll);
       //scroll.Content = questions[i];
       TitlePanel.Children.Add(ContentPanel);    
 }
```

text_question.Text = ""; which is commented in this function is wrapping while the public string doesn't wrap.

I want to use string out side any function then string have to public.

```
        private void next_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

          //  MessageBox.Show("Here is Next Question");
            a = a + 1;
            count.Text = a.ToString();
            if (a > 1)
            {
                previous.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            if (a == 5)
            {
                next.IsEnabled = false;
            }

            if (i >= 0 && i < questions.Length)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                scroll.Content = questions[i];                                       
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted here, the issue appears to be that you are never adding the TextBlock with the wrapping property set to the ScrollViewer. I would update this line:

```
scroll.Content = questions[0];
```

to:

```
scroll.Content = text_question;
```

and then manipulate text_question's content in the click event handlers.

---

That being said, I think you're making this far more complicated than it needs to be and making your UI code more complicated than necessary. I honestly can't think of a time that I've ever had a need to create UI controls in code and add them to the Children collection. Generally speaking, Windows Phone uses the MVVM pattern and your UI layout should be done via binding.

In this case, I'd do something like the following:

```
public class QuestionModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string[] _questions = new string[]
    {   
        "Question :\n What is OOPS?   \n\n Answer: \n  Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm based on the concept of objects which are data structures that contain data in the form of fields often known as attributes and code in the form of procedures often known as methods. There are a few principle concepts that form the foundation of object-oriented programming: 1- Object \n 2- Class \n 3- Abstraction \n 4- Polymorphism \n 5- Inheritance \n 6- Encapsulation \n 7- Overloading & OverRiding   ",
        "Question 2",
        "Question 3",
        "Question 4"
    };

    private int _selectedIndex = 0;


    public QuestionModel() {
        PrevCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => { 
            if(_selectedIndex > 0) {
                _selectedIndex--;
                selectedIndexChanged();
            }
        });
        NextCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => { 
            if(_selectedIndex < _questions.Length - 1) {
                _selectedIndex++;
                selectedIndexChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private void selectedIndexChanged() {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentQuestion");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("QuestionText");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsNextEnabled");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsPrevEnabled");
    }

    public int CurrentQuestion
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex + 1; }
    }

    public string QuestionText
    {
        get { return _questions[_selectedIndex]; }
    }

    public bool IsNextEnabled
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex < _questions.Length - 1; }
    }

    public bool IsPreviousEnabled
    {
       get { return _selectedIndex > 0; }
    }

    private ICommand _nextCommand;
    public ICommand NextCommand
    {
        get { return _nextCommand; }
        set
        {
            _nextCommand = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ICommand _prevCommand;
    public ICommand PrevCommand
    {
        get { return _prevCommand; }
        set
        {
            _prevCommand = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

#pragma warning disable 67
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
#pragma warning restore 67
}
```

Then in the XAML, I'd have the following:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:QuestionModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Question" Text="{Binding QuestionText}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Count" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,0" Text="{Binding CurrentQuestion, Mode=OneWay}">        
        </TextBlock>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="previous" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Content="Previous" IsEnabled="{Binding IsPreviousEnabled}" Command="{Binding PrevCommand}"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="next" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Content="Next" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNextEnabled}" Command="{Binding NextCommand}"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This way, there is no code in the code behind and you don't have to programatically create controls or modify the content. You just let the framework's data binding do the work for you and your model doesn't need to know how the UI puts everything together and vice versa.